# How to copy and paste 4th line a another file using python

Tags: python

I have txt file1 contains

```
line 1
line 2 
line 3
line 4 
line 5
```

Second text file contains

```
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
```

need to paste all 6,7,8,9 line in file 1 in 4th line how can do this using python

Comment: What do you mean "paste"? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert before line 4, write this:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r+'), open('file2.txt') as file1, file2:
    list = file1.readlines()
    list.insert(3, file2.readlines())
    file1.writelines(list)
```

To insert after, change the `3` to `4`.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to write it in third file and than rename it. Otherwise you have to read whole first file in RAM. This will work ok for huge files:

```
with open('file1', 'rb'), open('file2', 'rb'), open('file3', 'wb') as file1, file2, file3:
    ln = 1
    while ln < 4:
            ln+=1
            file3.write(file1.readline())
    for line in file2:
            file3.write(line)
    for line in file1:
            file3.write(line)
```